# Why onClick method inside tr is not calling the function in foreach Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to do something very simple, that is, making every row of my table clickable, when you click on the row should call a function to redirect you to another page, I did it with `jQuery` but it gave me certain problems with my `bootstrap tables` so I want to implement a solution with `js`, but when you click the row is not calling the function

This is my solution with jQuery, first when you click a row it will call a function that send the href to a form for the redirecting to the other page

```js
$(".clickable-row").click(function() {
                sendForm($(this).data("href"));
            });

function sendForm(projectId){
            console.log('works');
            $("#formProjectId").val(projectId);
            $("#Projectsform").submit();
        }
```

Here is my foreach

```html
 @foreach($projects

 as $project)
                    <tr class="clickable-row">
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" class="sl-color" onclick="sendForm('{{ $project->Project_Id }}')">{{ $project->Project_Id }}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $project->Project_Name }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

This is why I tried to do with `javascript` and its not working

```html
 @foreach($projects

 as $project)
                    <tr onclick="sendForm('{{ $project->Project_Id }}')">
                        <td>
                            {{ $project->Project_Name }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

Comment: If you `console.log(projectId)` inside `sendForm` what do you get?

Comment: Should you change the `a` to something else, like a `span`?

Comment: @Watercayman It doesn't print anything, I tried to print a simple `console.log('hi')` and it wasn't printed so is not calling the function

Comment: I don't get it why you call the function twice times. The onclick in a-tag is not necessary in last example.

Comment: @ShanerM13 the problem is not related to which tags should I put, is that the `onclick` function is not being called or is not working

Comment: Because it is failing above.  I'll stick an answer up in a sec

Comment: @enucar I called twice just  for the user to see the first item of the row clickable with an `a` but it will redirect you to the same page if you click It

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved,
I added on event function so if you click any items of the row it will call the `sendForm` function

```js
document.onclick = function(e){
            if(e.target.id == 'clickable-row'){
                sendForm(e.target.getAttribute("data-target"));
            }
        
        }
```

This is how my HTML looks like now, the `data-target` is for specifying the variables I want to pass to the function and the id to validate the exactly clicked element

```html
@foreach($projects

 as $project)
                    <tr>
                        <td id="clickable-row" data-target="{{ $project->Project_Id }}">
                            <a href="#" class="sl-color" onclick="sendForm('{{ $project->Project_Id }}')">{{ $project->Project_Id }}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td id="clickable-row" data-target="{{ $project->Project_Id }}">
                            {{ $project->Project_Name }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

Comment: This won't work (valid HTML) with `ids` writing over top of each other.  I suggest using the original answer I had with jquery (or the JS with the full document as I wrote) - it is doing the same thing, but cleanly.

Comment: Yours by somehow doesn't work for me properly, maybe It has to be with something else in the code, mine solved all my problems, I know its not the cleanest solution

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that js is failing in the first call, and thus never gets to the second call.  So from the original call:

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function() {
            sendForm($(this).data("href"));
    });
```

It is looking for the data field, but not finding a data element within the `<tr>`.  So it never hits the second call of the same function.

I think it would help to write this into one statement something like html:

```
  <span class='clickable' data-href='whatever your href is' data-id='{{ $project->Project_Id }}'>{{ $project->Project_Id }}</span>
```

Then call it via a click event in jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.clickable').on('click', function(){   
    var id = $(this).data( "id" );
    // same for href
   // then perform your actions
 });
});
```

In JS, you can do the same thing if you just have an onclick event:

```
function sendForm(projectId){
    document.getElementById("formProjectId").value = projectId;
    document.Projectsform.submit();
}
```

You'll need to make sure the `name` of the form is `Projectsform`, or:

```
document.getElementById("Projectsform").submit();
```

Comment: Sorry my bad I think there was a misunderstanding here, I want this to work `<tr onclick="sendForm('{{ $project->Project_Id }}')">`  the call that is inside the `a` tag works perfect.

The solution you have gave me is very similar as the one I did with the `jQuery`

Comment: No worries - so - the html with the `<tr class="clickable-row">` is no longer in your solution, it is just the `<tr onclick="sendForm('{{ $project->Project_Id }}')">` and that doesn't work?

Comment: @Yes exactly this is what I want`<tr onclick="sendForm('{{ $project->Project_Id }}')">` please post the solution with the js and then I accept your answer

Comment: If you've removed the first call from the `clickable-row` class, and you are just using the onclick from `<tr>`, if you can't `console.log(projectId)`, there is another problem, it's not the code here.  Does the browser console tell you any errors happening elsewhere on the page before it gets to this function?

Comment: I've added the solution in JS, but not sure if I understood if you had another problem or if it was successfully dumping the variable for you.

Answer (score 1):

mm Strange, you should remove the  tag due you are catching the parent tag click. check my pen.

https://codepen.io/ezequiel9/pen/MWJjGeq

```
$("body").on('click', '.clickable-row', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  sendForm($(this).data("href"));
});

function sendForm(projectId){
  alert('clicked');
  console.log('works');
  $("#formProjectId").val(projectId);
  $("#Projectsform").submit();
}
```

Comment: Sorry my bad I think there was a misunderstanding here, I want this to work `<tr onclick="sendForm('{{ $project->Project_Id }}')">`  the call that is inside the `a` tag works perfect.

The solution you have gave me is very similar as the one I did with the `jQuery` I want the parent tag click to work and is not working